# How to run the same script multiple times on one page?

Tags: html, jquery

I've created some HTML, CSS and JQuery to display a graph based on values in the div with the classname of "out".
I have a need for multiple graphs to be placed on the page. The problem I have is that when I try and place multiple graphs on the page, only the first one shows.
Is there a way I can call the same JQuery function multiple times on the same page and get it to operate correctly?

My code is below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".out div").each(function() {
    var num = $(this).html()
    var iNum = parseInt(num);
    var eq = $(this).index();
    var finalSum = (iNum / 20);
    $(".graph-div").eq(eq).find("div.graph-bar").css("height", finalSum + "px");
  });
});
```

```css
.graph-box {border:1px solid #ccc; width:fit-content;}
.graph-bar {width:120px; align-items: center; box-sizing: border-box;}
.graph {display:flex; text-align: center; width:90px; align-items: center; box-sizing: border-box;}
.graph-div {width:120px; align-self: flex-end;}
.out {display:flex; text-align: center;}
.parties {display:flex; border:1px solid #ccc; text-align: center; width: fit-content;}
.out div, .parties div {width:120px;}
.out div:nth-child(odd), .parties div:nth-child(odd)  {background-color:#F0F0F0;}
.out div:nth-child(even), .parties div:nth-child(even) {background-color:#F9f9f9;}
.con {background-color: blue;}
.lab {background-color: red;}
.gre {background-color: green;}
.lib {background-color: orange;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="graph-box">
  <div class="graph">
    <div class="graph-div">
      <div class="graph-bar con"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="graph-div">
      <div class="graph-bar lab"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="graph-div">
      <div class="graph-bar gre"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="graph-div">
      <div class="graph-bar lib"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="out">
    <div>1200</div>
    <div>7000</div>
    <div>160</div>
    <div>6899</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="parties">
  <div>Conservative</div>
  <div>labour</div>
  <div>Green</div>
  <div>Liberal <br> Democrats</div>
</div>

<div class="graph-box">
  <div class="graph">
    <div class="graph-div">
      <div class="graph-bar con"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="graph-div">
      <div class="graph-bar lab"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="graph-div">
      <div class="graph-bar gre"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="graph-div">
      <div class="graph-bar lib"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="out">
    <div>1200</div>
    <div>7000</div>
    <div>160</div>
    <div>6899</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="parties">
  <div>Conservative</div>
  <div>labour</div>
  <div>Green</div>
  <div>Liberal <br> Democrats</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Converted to a snippet - appears to work fine?

Comment: Are you sure this problem is directly related to CSS itself? What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I'm sorry I didn't make my post clear enough. What I'm trying to do is to get multiple graphs showing on the same page. I've edited the snippet code so it now breaks.

Comment: You seem to be stepping thro the divs in the first element with class out OK but I can’t see where you are then stepping onto the next element with class out to go thro it’s divs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because every single instance is only targeting the first set of graph bar outputs. You need to adjust your code to target the graph bars within the same parent - you can see here I've modified this line to scope the query properly and it shows two graphs now

```
$(this).closest(".graph-box").find(".graph-div")
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".out div").each(function() {
    var num = $(this).html()
    var iNum = parseInt(num);
    var eq = $(this).index();
    var finalSum = (iNum / 20);
    $(this).closest(".graph-box").find(".graph-div").eq(eq).find("div.graph-bar").css("height", finalSum + "px");
  });
});
```

```css
.graph-box {border:1px solid #ccc; width:fit-content;}
.graph-bar {width:120px; align-items: center; box-sizing: border-box;}
.graph {display:flex; text-align: center; width:90px; align-items: center; box-sizing: border-box;}
.graph-div {width:120px; align-self: flex-end;}
.out {display:flex; text-align: center;}
.parties {display:flex; border:1px solid #ccc; text-align: center; width: fit-content;}
.out div, .parties div {width:120px;}
.out div:nth-child(odd), .parties div:nth-child(odd)  {background-color:#F0F0F0;}
.out div:nth-child(even), .parties div:nth-child(even) {background-color:#F9f9f9;}
.con {background-color: blue;}
.lab {background-color: red;}
.gre {background-color: green;}
.lib {background-color: orange;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="graph-box">
  <div class="graph">
    <div class="graph-div">
      <div class="graph-bar con"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="graph-div">
      <div class="graph-bar lab"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="graph-div">
      <div class="graph-bar gre"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="graph-div">
      <div class="graph-bar lib"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="out">
    <div>1200</div>
    <div>7000</div>
    <div>160</div>
    <div>6899</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="parties">
  <div>Conservative</div>
  <div>labour</div>
  <div>Green</div>
  <div>Liberal <br> Democrats</div>
</div>

<div class="graph-box">
  <div class="graph">
    <div class="graph-div">
      <div class="graph-bar con"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="graph-div">
      <div class="graph-bar lab"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="graph-div">
      <div class="graph-bar gre"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="graph-div">
      <div class="graph-bar lib"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="out">
    <div>1200</div>
    <div>7000</div>
    <div>160</div>
    <div>6899</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="parties">
  <div>Conservative</div>
  <div>labour</div>
  <div>Green</div>
  <div>Liberal <br> Democrats</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Your issue is this line:

```
var eq = $(this).index();
```

which will give you the index only within `this`'s parent - so the *fifth* `div` across all `out` is actually index==0 because it's the first div in the second `out`.

So when you do `$(".graph-div").eq(eq)`, eq==0 so will find the *first* .graph-div across *all* graph-divs.

You have some options, including:

1. link the data with the graph, eg using `data-` attributes

this would be the most flexible as the order and position/structure of the HTML would not matter, but may be overkill in this scenario

2. limit `$(".graph-div")` selection to match the `out`

details in other answer - requires restructuring the HTML, which may not be appropriate in all cases

3. change `.index()` to apply across all `out` divs:

requires that out/graphs are all in the same order (which makes sense otherwise they won't line up...)

To apply `.index()` across all `out` divs:

```
var eq = $(".out div").index(this);
```

or

```
var eq = $(this).index(".out div");
```

the first would allow you to cache `$(".out div")` - not below shown for clarity of the change.

Which option you choose depends on how you layout the HTML

Updated snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".out div").each(function() {
    var num = $(this).html()
    var iNum = parseInt(num);
    //var eq = $(this).index();
    var eq = $(".out div").index(this);
    //var eq = $(this).index(".out div");
    var finalSum = (iNum / 20);
    $(".graph-div").eq(eq).find("div.graph-bar").css("height", finalSum + "px");
  });
});
```

```css
.graph-box {border:1px solid #ccc; width:fit-content;}
.graph-bar {width:120px; align-items: center; box-sizing: border-box;}
.graph {display:flex; text-align: center; width:90px; align-items: center; box-sizing: border-box;}
.graph-div {width:120px; align-self: flex-end;}
.out {display:flex; text-align: center;}
.parties {display:flex; border:1px solid #ccc; text-align: center; width: fit-content;}
.out div, .parties div {width:120px;}
.out div:nth-child(odd), .parties div:nth-child(odd)  {background-color:#F0F0F0;}
.out div:nth-child(even), .parties div:nth-child(even) {background-color:#F9f9f9;}
.con {background-color: blue;}
.lab {background-color: red;}
.gre {background-color: green;}
.lib {background-color: orange;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="graph-box">
  <div class="graph">
    <div class="graph-div">
      <div class="graph-bar con"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="graph-div">
      <div class="graph-bar lab"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="graph-div">
      <div class="graph-bar gre"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="graph-div">
      <div class="graph-bar lib"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="out">
    <div>1200</div>
    <div>7000</div>
    <div>160</div>
    <div>6899</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="parties">
  <div>Conservative</div>
  <div>labour</div>
  <div>Green</div>
  <div>Liberal <br> Democrats</div>
</div>

<div class="graph-box">
  <div class="graph">
    <div class="graph-div">
      <div class="graph-bar con"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="graph-div">
      <div class="graph-bar lab"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="graph-div">
      <div class="graph-bar gre"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="graph-div">
      <div class="graph-bar lib"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="out">
    <div>3500</div>
    <div>7000</div>
    <div>6000</div>
    <div>6899</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="parties">
  <div>Conservative</div>
  <div>labour</div>
  <div>Green</div>
  <div>Liberal <br> Democrats</div>
</div>
```